# What happens when hdfs-site.xml is different in namenode and datanode?

Tags: hdfs

Do we expect some sort of a failure, or do certain settings take precedence?

In my particular case, I forgot to set the min replication factor to the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to maintain the same hdfs-site.xml on every node.

In your case:

Suppose Namenode contains a replication of 3 and Datanode has its value set to 1.

What will happen now is that the Namenode will try to replicate the Data on to 3 Datanodes and Datanode will have its replication of 1. So in case you only have not more than 2 Datanodes then your Namenode will keep on trying to create 3 replicas of the data but it will end up making only 1 replica. And you'll get an Under-replicated blocks error.

Which is why every property should be same in every node.